# Bootstrap 3 Forms. Alignment when adding columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to play with adding columns to my bootstrap forms.

```
    <section class="test-form">
        <h3>Test Form</h3>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <select name="" class="form-control">
                <!-- Various Options -->
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <select class="form-control" name="" >
                <!-- Various Options -->
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Test Button 1</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 2</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 3</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 6</button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The problem with the above is that my desired output is as follows:

The left side of `test button 2` and `test button 4` should be inline with the left side of `test button 1`.

The right side of `test button 3` and right side of `test button 6` should be in-line with the right side of `test button 1`

Any advice on the correct way of achieving this?

Screenshot to explain below.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the actual output? Wich is the desired output?

Comment: The left side of `test button 2` and `test button 4` should be inline with the left side of `test button 1` and the right side of `test button 3` and right side of `test button 6` should be in-line with the right side of `test button 1`

Comment: That "gap" is caused for the padding that col elements have ... You will need to override that

Comment: just wrap all the divs with a `.col` class in a div with a `.row` class and the alignment should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing you are seeing is caused by the padding bootstrap adds to `col-*` classes. You can either override this padding for those elements or wrap all the elements of the form in a row and add a `col-*` class wrapping div to elements which don't have this class.

Here is an example of the latter.
HTML:

```
<section class="test-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Test Form</h3>
      <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <select name="" class="form-control">
          <!-- Various Options -->
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <select class="form-control" name="" >
          <!-- Various Options -->
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Test Button 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 3</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Test Button 6</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/1H1KXSAVqm

Answer (score 0):

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/S0f6WvKWaF)

The quickest fix I found was doing this:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-12">
        <select name="" class="form-control">
            <!-- Various Options -->
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control" name="" >
            <!-- Various Options -->
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-12">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Test Button 1</button>
    </div>
```

Basically, where you didn't have the right padding, I added a `col-xs-12` class to style them similar to the rest of your inputs.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved what it sounds like you are going for.

```
<div class='row'>
     <div class='col-md-6 column'>
     *Inputs*
     </div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
     <div class='col-md-6 column'>
     *Inputs*
     </div>
</div>
```